# How can I fix my code for clearing nodes in a linked structure

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I asked something similar earlier but now I have run into a different problem.
Can you please look at it? I am trying to free the nodes in a linked structure created in my program.
Here is the structure.

```
struct node {
    unsigned x;
    double y;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node Nodes, *This;
```

Declaration of the functions

```
void freeNodes(Nodes *a);
void freeThis(This *);
```

Function `freeNodes`:

```
void freeNodes(Nodes *a) 
{ free(a);
  print ("success");

}
```

Function `freeThis`:

I don't know how to fix this so I can free the nodes from the whole linked list.

```
void freeThis(This *p)
    {
       Nodes *tmp;

       while (p != NULL)
        {

            (*tmp) = Nodes *p;
            *p=(*p)->next;

         freeNodes(tmp);
         tmp = NULL;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why do people make life so hard for themselves?  The `This` type should be lost; don't define pointer types like `This` and simply use `Nodes *` where you would otherwise use `This`.  (Oh, and it means I have to think harder to help you, so it will mean you get more help quicker if you make the code easier for people to understand.)  Incidentally, the posted code doesn't compile: `(*tmp) = Nodes *p;` is not valid C.  Note that the `success` message won't appear until you add a newline to the output.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
void freeThis(This *p){
    Nodes *tmp;

    if(!p) return;

    while (*p != NULL){
        tmp = *p;
        *p=(*p)->next;

        freeNodes(tmp);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the `This` type, as I noted in a comment.  It makes it harder (for me) to understand what is going on.  (I don't suppose it makes it easier for you either, but I might be wrong about that.)

Given that it exists, then:

```
void freeThis(This *p)
{
    if (p != 0)
    {
        Nodes *tmp = *p;
        *p = NULL;

        while (tmp != NULL)
        {
            Nodes *next = tmp->next;
            freeNodes(tmp);
            tmp = next;
        }
    }
}
```